# How are token symbols allocated and managed on the mainnet?

Tags: airdrops

How is the token symbols namespace managed on the mainnet? How are token symbols allocated? Are they "attached" to the smart contract? ie we can have many tokens with the same token name?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the token is attached to the smart contract, and the smart contract is attached to an account. Whenever you transfer tokens, you have to specify the account on which the smart contract for those tokens is uploaded.